# Web Dynamic Project in Eclipse shows Error:404 for any other page after index.html

Tags: html, spring-mvc, web.xml

I created a Web Dynamic Project and generated a web.xml file. Then I copied my servlet from a website and changed it's specifications to my project's specifications. I copied the web.xml and servlet in WebContent folder by mistake but the project did work at that time. When I realized that these 2 files must be put in WEB-INF, I replaced them and now the project is not able to find even my `index.html`.
This is my project hierarchy :

[image]

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>zingyBees</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zingyBees</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is my zingyBees-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">

    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.project"></ctx:component-scan>
    <!--Add support for conversion, formatting and validation -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="webTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Thymeleaf Template Resolver -->
    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
        <property name="checkExistence" value="true"/>
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>



     <!-- Thymeleaf View Resolver - implementation of Spring's ViewResolver interface -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Thymeleaf Template Engine (Spring4-specific version) -->
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolvers">
            <set>
                <ref bean="templateResolver" />
                <!-- <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" /> -->       
                <ref bean="webTemplateResolver" />
                <!-- <ref bean="UrlTemplateResolver" /> -->
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And this is my index.html:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="indexApp" data-ng-controller="indexController">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Home Page</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ZingyBeesTest/style.css" type="text/css">

<script>

var myApp=angular.module('indexApp',[]).config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled : true,
        requireBase : false
    }); 
});

myApp.run(function($http) {});

myApp.controller('indexController',function($scope,$http,$location){
    console.log("controller working");
    $scope.contactUs=function(){
        console.log("Inside angular");

        var res=$http.get("/ZingyBeesTest/display/contactUs")
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });  

    }

});

</script>   

</head>
<body>
<!-- NAV-BAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/ZingyBeesTest/index.html" target="_self">
        <b>Zingy Bees</b>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#" target="_self">
                    Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="WebContent/WEB-INF/html/about-us.html" target="_self">About ZB</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="./WEB-INF/html/contact-us.html" target="_self">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/WEB-INF/html/enroll-form.html" target="_self">Enroll</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<!-- Connect -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./connect.txt"></script>

<!-- Footer -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./footer.txt"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

My html folder in WEB-INF contains all the files I want to use in my navbar.

Answer (score 0):

No files in the `WEB-INF` folder can be directly accessed as the `WEB-INF` node is not a part of the **document tree** of the application. The files of the WEB-INF folder can be accessed by other methods in `Java Controllers` or `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` method calls on `ServletContext`. **So the files in the WEB-INF folder are not directly visible to the public.**